# Get GROUP_BY values as strings

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by, group-concat

I have this simple table called questions:

```
id | asker
 1 | Bob
 2 | Marley
 3 | Bob
```

I want to get a comma-separated list of the asker values. I use the following query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(asker) FROM questions
```

This will result in:

```
Bob,Marley,Bob
```

I want it instead to result like this:

```
'Bob','Marley','Bob'
```

Thanks

Comment: One hesitates to ask... but _why_ do you need that? (On a side note: you're screwed if `asker` can contain a comma).

Comment: I want to use that string inside a "NOT IN()" parameter of another query so it has to act like a string or otherwise mysql would assume these are column names

Comment: Why not have that in one query with a `NOT EXISTS()`?

Comment: sorry can't understand you...do you mean using NOT EXTITS() instead of NOT IN()?

Comment: Yep `SELECT ....your query ..... WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT asker FROM questions WHERE asker = somefieldinyourquery)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original didn't quite work in mySQL.

Addressing Wrikken's very valid concern

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(concat('''',asker,'''')) FROM questions
```

Comment: asker won't contain commas or any other characters except letters...so your previous solution is the correct one :)

Comment: Hah, only letters save time, because my next issue would be with `'`'s in the `questions.asker` field...

Comment: so what's the problem again? This is in case questions.asker has what value??

Comment: The previous one was simpler and working...so would you edit it back again?? Also Wrikken assumes an issue that i  can't understand...anyways can you return back the previous answer?? thanks :)